# Source path in SSH SFTP sampler when directory listing configure is used

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is Upload more than one file to the remote(SFTP) server. For this i am using SFTP sampler to connect to server and directory listing config to put more than file
Here what i should give in Source path of SSH SFTP sampler.

if i keep sorce path as empty gets file not found exception

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Introducing the Directory Listing Config Plugin on JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) article you need to use the following pattern:

`Source Directory` `Destination variable name`

For example if you have the following Directory Listing Config setup:

[image]

You should go for the following pattern:

```
/tmp/somefolder${currentFile}
```

[image]

Remember that you can always use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see which variables are generated:

[image]